# /sys/class/leds/asus\:\:kbd_backlight missing

Tags: drivers, keyboard, asus

I have an ASUS GM501GM and it seems the keyboard backlight module isn't working.
The keyboard works, except for special keys and the backlight.
Any idea how to get it running?